# Unsure if i have sidebar scroll on mobile

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive

im pretty new to html and css and have no idea what im doing, trying to make a responsive website and i was just checking how it looks on other devices using chrome developer tools, and for some reason i'll inspect it and it has a side scroll bar, but then if i literally dont change the code and just close the web tools and reopen them and try again theres no scroll bar, idk why its doing that,

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxqSM.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqJ0t.png)

i wonder if its my code or web tools just bugging, but it doesn't seem to be doing it on any other sites.

https://jsfiddle.net/p7yo3u06/1/

PS : i have no idea what im doing i've never used fiddle before its saying i have to post the code here aswell as the fiddle link

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 

<html lang="en"> 

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> 
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/3f739494fd.js"
 crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="Mobile.css">
</head> 


<body> 

    <div class="topbar"> 
    

<div class="secondtopbar"> 



<div class="navflex"> 
    <a href="#" class="Home">  Home  </a>
    <a href="#">  Our Projects </a>
    <a href="#"> Contact Us </a>
    <a href="#">  FAQ </a>
</div>



        <a href="#" class="quote"> Get A Free Quote </a>

        <div class="threebars mobile"> 
            <i class="fa-2x fa-solid fa-bars" style="color: #ffffff;"></i>
        </div>

        
     <img class="title" src="Titletext2.png">
  

        <div class="phone mobile"> 
        <i class="fa-2x fa-solid fa-phone"  style="color: #ffffff;" ></i>
    </div>
    
    

</div>

</div>

   
    
</body>


</html>
```

CSS

> :root {
>
> ```
> --primary-color : rgb(226, 45, 45);
> ```
>
> --topbar-color :rgb(51, 52, 53);
> --banner-color : #231f20;
>
> }
>
> - {
>
>   margin : 0;
>   box-sizing : border-box!important;
>   border : 1px soli;
>   outline: 1px red solid !important; visibility: visible !important
>   }
>
> .secondtopbar img {
>
> width : 300px; height : 66px;
>
> }
>
> a {
>
> ```
> text-decoration : none;
> font-family : Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
> padding : 5px;
> margin-left : 1vw;
> color : white; }
> ```
>
> a, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, p {
>
> color : white; font-family : system-ui, -apple-system,
> BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen,  Ubuntu, Cantarell,
> 'Open Sans',   'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
>
> }
>
> .Home {
>
> ```
> background-color : var(--primary-color);
> ```
>
> }
>
> .mobile {
>
> ```
> display : none;
> background-color : red;
> padding : 10px }
> ```
>
> .navflex {
>
> ```
> display : flex; }
> ```
>
> .quote {
>
> ```
> background-color : var(--primary-color);
> margin-right : 1vw;
> border : 1px solid; }
> ```
>
> .secondtopbar {
>
> ```
> margin : 0 6v;
> justify-content : space-between;
> display : flex; }
> ```
>
> .title {
>
> ```
> display : none;
> ```
>
> }
>
> .topbar {
>
> ```
> background-color : var(--topbar-color);
> border-bottom : rgb(255, 0, 0) solid 2px;
> padding : 5px 0;
> ```
>
> }
>
> /* Mobile  Styles */
>
> @media all and (max-width: 630px) {
>
> ```
> .mobile { 
>
>     display : block;
> }
> ```
>
> .navflex { display : none;}
>
> .quote {
>
> ```
> display : none; }
> ```
>
> .secondtopbar {
>
> ```
> margin : 0 10px;
> ```
>
> }
>
> .title {
>
> ```
> display : block; }
> ```
>
> }